# How to implement google organic tag in google tag manager

Tags: php, seo, google-tag-manager, conversion-tracking

I am learning google tag manager and have applied the google analytics,adwords and social network tracking codes in google tag manager.Also have triggered the tags on pages and tested them.
But now I have to implement google organic tags for SEO purpose on our site and I really dont found something useful for doing that.
If anyone can explain that what is the actual use of google organic and how we implement it using google tag manager then its really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: have you checked https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gtm and http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/12/30/seo-reporting-google-tag-manager/ and http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/11/24/schema-metadata-google-tag-manager/ ?? Have a look at all 3 links

Comment: I have checked that link http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/12/30/seo-reporting-google-tag-manager/ before but not get it properly as the datalayer keyword and variables for tracking google|yahoo|bing

Comment: oww.. may be you should ask this question at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.. may be someone from webmasters may have the answer

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Google Organic Tag".  Can you describe what you are after ?

Comment: I want to track the url clicks and ad clicks on site and from which search engine they are coming from also want to know more about google organic

Comment: Use Google Analytics, which has reports on all advertising channels including organic search. There is extensive documentation, so I suggest you just try it and get back to SO with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need event listeners and auto event tracking to do this perfectly in Tag Manager. Read both of these links and follow Just Cutroni's step by step guide to get exactly what you need, and a whole lot of extra event tracking functionality:

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3415369?hl=en

http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/10/07/auto-event-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/

As for the Google Organic click tracking, you need to use the "Search engine optimisation" report in Google Analytics and review Queries / Search Impact reports in Webmaster Tools.

Comment: " to do this perfectly in Tag Manager" - to do what, exactly ? There is no "google organic tag", and Analytics (which the OP claims to have implemented) includes data on organic search in any case.

Comment: To do the bit described in the comment below the initial question. I.e. 
"I want to track the url clicks and ad clicks on site"

Answer (score 0):

As you have implemented google analytics, adwords and social network tracking codes in GTM already, it takes care of organic traffic as well as paid traffic.
There is no additional set up required provided it is set up to capture pageviews as well as events.